# load uiwebview in uipopover

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, uipopovercontroller

In my app each time user clicks on a url, an uipopover will pop up displaying the website.
The problem is the popover is just 320x480 but the uiwebview is as big as a iPad view.

How can I make uiwebview to load the website in a smaller view.

Thanks.
Here is part of my code:

```
- (IBAction)openWeb:(id)sender{
    ShowWebOnBrowserViewController *swobvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebView"];
    swobvc.title = self.companyName.text;
    swobvc.companyWebURL = self.web.titleLabel.text;

swobvc.companyWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
swobvc.companyWebView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,480);
swobvc.companyWebView.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
swobvc.companyWebView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

    popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:swobvc];

    popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
    [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:[((UIButton*)sender) bounds] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}

//in popover class
-(IBAction)loadURL:(id)sender
{    
    NSString* webText = self.companyWebURL;
    webText = [webText stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:webText];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webURL];
    [self.companyWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
    self.companyWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the openWeb method, set the frame of the companyWebView before presenting the popOver.  Also, ensure that scalesPageToFit is also set to YES (NO is the default).

```
//...cut...
popOverController.companyWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

popOverController.companyWebView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,480);

popOverController.companyWebView.frame = CGRectMake(popOverController.companyWebView.frame.origin.x, popOverController.companyWebView.frame.origin.y, 320, 480);
//...cut...
```

Do you have control of the website content?  Try adding a meta tag to set the viewport there, like:

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what it looks like in the simulator?

Comment: Additionally, set the contentSize on the webview's scrollView property like I added in the answer.

Comment: Thanks again, but it didn't work either. I added one image as well.